# How to parse this Dialogflow request / response in Java

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

guys.
We have developed a couple of chatbots using Dialogflow and we need to keep all messages between the bots and the users in elastic. The messages are sent to Stackdriver from where we read them. What we get is something like this:

Request:

```
{"insertId":"sdfgsdfgsdfg","labels":{"protocol":"V2_BETA1","request_id":"26e57863-387f-4b93-b5fb-135bc83bcd25-dd2bbea9","type":"dialogflow_request"},"logName":"projects/projectname/logs/dialogflow_agent","receiveTimestamp":"2020-03-27T11:57:58.150171409Z","resource":{"labels":{"project_id":"projectname"},"type":"global"},"severity":"INFO","textPayload":"Dialogflow Request : {\"session\":\"10001000061585310270\",\"query_input\":\"{\\n  \\\"text\\\": {\\n    \\\"textInputs\\\": [{\\n      \\\"text\\\": \\\"user input here\\\"\\n    }]\\n  }\\n}\",\"timezone\":\"Europe/Madrid\"}","timestamp":"2020-03-27T11:57:58.096Z","trace":"10001000061585310270"}
```

Response:

```
{
    "insertId":"116tnvwg3zk2dlm"
    "labels":{
        "protocol":"V2_BETA1"
        "request_id":"25676788-5663-b5fb-135b-c83bcd25fghf-dfgdr545"
        "type":"dialogflow_response"
    }
    "logName":"projects/myprojectid/logs/dialogflow_agent"
    "receiveTimestamp":"2020-03-10T10:35:58.150171409Z"
    "resource":{
        "labels":{
            "project_id":"myprojectid"
        }
        "type":"global"
    }
    "severity":"INFO"
    "textPayload":"Dialogflow Response : id: \"25676788-5663-b5fb-135b-c83bcd25fghf-dfgdr545\"\nlang: \"es\"\nsession_id: \"12126565412631623162\"\ntimestamp: \"2020-03-10T10:35:58.134Z\"\nresult {\n  source: \"agent\"\n  resolved_query: \"user request here\"\n  score: 0.676\n  parameters {\n    fields {\n      key: \"medida\"\n      value {\n        list_value {\n          values {\n            string_value: \"grande\"\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    fields {\n      key: \"sabores\"\n      value {\n        list_value {\n          values {\n            string_value: \"fresa\"\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  contexts {\n    name: \"haveorder\"\n    lifespan: 5\n    parameters {\n      fields {\n        key: \"medida\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"grande\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"medida.original\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"grande\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"sabores\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"fresa\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"sabores.original\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"fresa\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  contexts {\n    name: \"promptedpayment\"\n    lifespan: 5\n    parameters {\n      fields {\n        key: \"medida\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"grande\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"medida.original\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"grande\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"sabores\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"fresa\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"sabores.original\"\n        value {\n          list_value {\n            values {\n              string_value: \"fresa\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  metadata {\n    intent_id: \"6685717b-381b-4ce5-8947-52d0080abf67\"\n    intent_name: \"0 - getOrder\"\n    webhook_used: \"false\"\n    webhook_for_slot_filling_used: \"false\"\n    is_fallback_intent: \"false\"\n  }\n  fulfillment {\n    speech: \"¡Claro! Uno de fresa grande ahora mismo. ¿Cómo vas a pagar? ¿Con efectivo o con tarjeta?\"\n    messages {\n      lang: \"es\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"¡Claro! Uno de fresa grande ahora mismo. ¿Cómo vas a pagar? ¿Con efectivo o con tarjeta?\"\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\nstatus {\n  code: 200\n  error_type: \"success\"\n}\n"
    "timestamp":"2020-03-10T10:35:58.14Z"
    "trace":"12126565412631623162"
}
```

The information we're interested in is inside textPayload but I can't find any way to turn textPayload into something I can manipulate using Java.

Applying a few regular expressions I can (not always) turn that text into a json and work with it, but the solution doesn't seem very robust.Can you think of a better solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could remove the initial "Dialogflow Response :" from the string, and then just do a String.replaceAll("{", ": {"). That should turn it into valid json

Comment: Thanks @devil0150, but there are no commas in that text. Anyway, as I said, applying some regular expressions, I can turn that text into a valid json, but I'm not comfortable with that solution. I think that text is the result of an ObjectX.toString() and I'd love to know what that ObjectX is :)